# SQL multiple values in Where = "N"

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going to execute SQL command on my multiplayer game, I don't wanna any game stop or something like that because I am going to lose players so everything must go smooth.

Its my command :

```
UPDATE `players`
   SET `mana` = `mana` + 500 WHERE `vocation` != "121;122;123;124;125;126" 
   AND `id` IN (SELECT `player_id` FROM `player_storage` WHERE `key` = 25128 AND `value` = 15 GROUP BY `player_id`);
```

I want to update every vocation that is not 121 OR 122 OR 123 OR 124 OR 125 OR 126

Comment: Frankly, I'm afraid that this is a mess.

Comment: uhm ty for editing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT IN` to filter values that are not in a list.

```
WHERE vocation NOT IN (121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BETWEEN`

```
     ....Where location
    not between 120 
    and 
    127
```

Comment: While this will work for this particular situation, `NOT IN` would be closer to the original intent.

Comment: But adding manual values and that too at such frequencies would be a bad practice. This works for all consecutive data just that replace the between values

Comment: suppose vocation # 130 needs to be added to the list, or #125 removed - what do you do? I'm not saying it's a _terrible_ solution, but there no obvious relationship between these IDs to indicate that a `between` is a natural way to think of them - they just _happen_ to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list as a string of values with delimiter `;` you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`vocation`, REPLACE('121;122;123;124;125;126', ';', ',')) = 0
```